# How to add Custom Fields in Wordpress Posts?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have seen many asking how to insert custom Fields in Wordpress post? Even though plugins are available nothing is a single-click solution.We need to do a bit of adjustments to make it work.Today I ended up doing that to improve the appearance and usability of my theme as it didn't have those built in options.Since,I struggled a lot to make it work I thought of sharing it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the main steps:

Install the [Custom Field Template](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template).
Navigate to `Appearance > Editor` and include this code snippet in your `functions.php` file:

```
function getCustomField($theField) {
    global $post;
    $block = get_post_meta($post->ID, $theField);
    if($block){
        foreach(($block) as $blocks) {
            echo $blocks;
        }
    }
}
```

Configure the custom fields by going to `Settings > Custom Field Template,` expand the template content section, and add something like this:

```
[Day Number]
type = text
size = 10
output = true
```

Note: Unless you add output = true, the custom fields won’t work.

Go to `Appearance > Editor` and add this code into the template (such as single.php) where you want the value of the custom field to appear:

To add a conditional statement around the getCustomField function (so that it only appears under certain conditions, such as the post being in a specific category), include this before the getCustomField function:

… then insert your getCustomField functions …

and then close with this:
Hope this helps you.